# Is there a way to zip an entire s3 directory and leave the zip there without downloading it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to aws and I want to zip a directory in aws and get the zipped s3 URL in lambda. Currently I am using s3-zip module for that. But it downloads the zip directly. I actually dont want to download it. I want it to be zipped in the bucket itself. Is there a way for this? I have shared my code below

```
    const params = {
    Bucket: S3BucketConfig.bucket,
    Prefix: folder
  }
  
  const filesArray = []
  const files = s3.listObjects(params).createReadStream()

  const xml = new XmlStream(files)
  xml.collect('Key')
  xml.on('endElement: Key', function(item) {
    filesArray.push(item['$text'].substr(folder.length))
  })
  xml
    .on('end', function () {
      zip(filesArray)
    })
  
  function zip(files) {
    const output = fs.createWriteStream(join(__dirname, fileName))
    s3Zip
     .archive({ region: "eu-west-1", bucket: S3BucketConfig.bucket, preserveFolderStructure: true }, folder, files)
     .pipe(output)
  }
```

Can anyone help me with this ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

> I want it to be zipped in the bucket itself. Is there a way for this?

Sadly there is not. S3 is **not a filesystem**, it is [object storage](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/). This means that you can't perform modification on the objects "inside" a bucket.

Your zip operation will need to download all objects that you want to archive, **zip them locally** (e.g. on ec2 instance, lambda function, local workstation), and then upload the zip to the bucket.

The [s3-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-zip) downloads the objects and packs them into zip. There is no way for this, or other module, to perform zipping operation "in" a bucket, without downloading the objects first. The object's don't have to be physically stored locally before zipping, as they can be streamed from S3, but still its not "in" the bucket.